# How to locate a module being imported in python

Tags: python, import, nltk

I am trying to locate how the following line of code in nltk is loading the module *gutenberg*

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
```

I tried using `.__file__` on nltk.corpus and it points to an `__init__.py` file. I was expecting to see a function or class called *gutenberg* in the `__init__.py` file, but couldn't find it.

I don't think I fully understand how import works. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that `__init__.py`, you can see these lines:

```
gutenberg = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'gutenberg', PlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!\.).*\.txt')
```

That is the object you are importing.  The things you can import are not limited to classes and functions; you can import any object from a module --- a class, a function, an instance of a class, an integer, a string, whatever.  In this case it is an instance of the LazyCorpusLoader class, which is a class nltk uses to manage its corpora.